# What is 'always' modifying?

Tags: adverbs

> 1. There's always somebody at home in the evenings.
> 2. We're not always this busy!
> 3. Ellie always was very good at art.

I think it is modifying 'is, are, was'.
Can't I think 'is, are, was' mean 'exist'?
It seems to be quite well explained to me if it means 'exist' because by so, we can think always is modifying 'exist'.

as in

> 1. There always exists somebody at home in the evenings.
> 2. We do not always exist this busy!
> 3. Ellie always exists very good at art.

For me, these do not mean different from the sentences above.

Comment: It's a modifier in clause structure in all your examples.

Comment: In your examples, always is modifying the verb" to be" in both its positive and negative states.

Comment: For review: always, never/ever, sometimes, adverbs of frequency. All three of your second set of  sentences are wrong. We simply say: to be busy, to be good at art, to be at home

Answer (score 1):

You are along the right line, but do not confused *state of be-ing* verbs with existance.

Your sentences could be restated as

> There **always is** somebody at home in the evenings.
>   **Not always are** we this busy!
>   Ellie **was always** very good at art.